# how can i reduce the data fetch time with mongo in a bigger datasize

Tags: performance, mongodb

We have a collection(name_list) of 30 million 'names'. We are comparing  this 30 million records with 4 million 'names'. We are fetching these 4  million 'names' from a txt file.

I am using PHP and Linux platform. I gave index for 'names' field. I am  using simple 'find' to compare data with mongodb with txt file's data
$collection->findOne(array('names' => $name_from_txt))

I am comparing one by one. I Know join is not possible in mongodb.Is there any better method to compare data in mongodb?

The OS and other details are as follows.

OS : Ubuntu
Kernel Version : 3.5.0-23-generic
64 bit
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
CPU info - 24
Memory - 64G
Disks 3 - out of which mongo is written to a fusion i/o disk of size 320G
File system on mongo disk - ext4 with noatime as mentioned in mongo doc
ulimit settings for mongo changed to 65000
readahead is 32
numa is disabled with --interleave option

when i use a script to compare this, it takes around 5 min to complete ... what can be done, so that it gets executed faster and finish in say 1-2 min ? can anyone help please?

Comment: I remember this question from else where, maybe it has been posted before or it was posted on google group

Comment: actually when i compare 1 million data against 30 million, i get the results fetched in 3 minute ..

when i compare 4 million data against 30 million, it takes 18 min to fetch the result ..

so i want to know what can be done to reduce these times and get faster outputs

Comment: yes i have posted in google groups as well, but havnt received a reply yet

Comment: Are you sure this is the databases problem if that is the case? If mean if the database find is performing well there must be something odd with fetching that larger text file

Comment: What if you broke the text file into grpoups of 1 million and then read them each time you needed them?

Comment: Also take a look at mongostat and see if you are getting a stupidly high rate of page faults

Comment: Ah hang on I misread the time it takes to get 1 million. One basic question, have you made sure you have a index on that field?

Comment: How long does it take to read all "names" into a hash object, how long to read all names from file, and then compare locally?

Comment: faults always shows 0 ... given below is a sample from mongostat when the script is being run

Comment: insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults            locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
    *0   4000     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    12g  24.2g  1.34g      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0   399k   146k     2   01:39:14 
    *0   3751     *0     *0       0     2|0       0    12g  24.2g  1.34g      0 db_list_restore:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0   375k   137k     2   01:39:15

Comment: to read from a 1 million csv file, it took me 7 seconds